# Access 2010: Refresh Navigation Pane and Sum/Avg not visible on report

Tags: user-interface, report, refresh, ms-access-2010

I have noticed a strange problem in Access 2010: when a user creates a new object (table, form, query, ...), this object does not show up in the navigation pane. It only does so after manually refreshing the navigation pane (F5) or after closing and reopening the access file. Furthermore, when previewing a report, the Sums and Averages do not show up until the user clicks on the field(s). Printing the report is ok.

This behaviour is machine dependant, the same file behaves correctly on other PCs. I was looking at the video cards installed on different PCs, but they all have Intel(R) HD Graphics.

Any ideas anyone?

Cheers

Comment: re: new objects not appearing in the Navigation Pane - I had that happen on one of my machines a few months ago. Running the Office installer from the "Programs" control panel and choosing "Repair" fixed it in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was indeed solved by repairing Office 2010

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues with imported tables not showing up in the tables list and new queries also not showing up in the queries list. Re-installing Access fixed my issues.